# I need a cocoa bean farm but my world doesn't have any jungles!

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm playing on a Minecraft world in (Legacy) Playstation 4 Edition (5x5 maps) and I've spent about a week filling out the entire world and I don't have a single jungle. The thing is I need a cocoa bean farm and I don't have either cocoa beans or jungle wood. I hear cocoa beans can be traded from the wandering trader but that doesn't solve my wood problem. Is there anywhere I can get jungle saplings or wood without actually having a jungle? I didn't start with a bonus chest.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to get both resources from a wandering trader. Referencing the [wikia article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading#Bedrock_Edition_sales) for the wander it is possible to trade five emeralds for a jungle sapling. Cocoa beans can be purchased for three emeralds.

While unlikely, the resource is available via the wandering trader.